# How to count from active cell to the top?

Tags: vba, excel

I basically have an address in which I would like to offset to the top cell (1,1). In this case the cell I have is $A$4, but could be anywhere in the A column. I'd like to count how many cells are between $A$4 and $A$1 so that I can use it to offset and copy/paste something. In this case I'd be looking for the count to be 3.

I'm currently using

```
cnt = wb.Sheets(sht.Name).Range("firstAddress", ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
```

firstAddress in this case is ($A$4) but I believe I'm going about this completely wrong.

Comment: I don't think so, that makes count = 26

Comment: Is `"firstAddress"` a named range? Is it always going to be a single cell?  Also, what are you trying to do there? Your main question may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: "firstAddress" is a named range, and it will always be a single cell in the first column (A). I'm somewhat new to vba excel and thought that if I could count rows from the bottom up to cell(1,1) then I would have the number I need.